# The post block of redaction, which is waiting for an approvement, is out of the borders in the Mod control panel

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, revision-redaction

`/admin/dashboard`

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow, only 3 years eh, there's an SLA for you ha. Should be all good now!

Comment: Well, it used to be 6-8 weeks :D

Comment: Feels old man...